# How to call a controller function from a view, then reload the same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to have a link on my show page which will call a function on the controller, then reload the show page.

I'm working with the SNMP gem, and the function would toggle the administratively up/down setting on a specific switch interface.

I'd need to pass in the current @node and an interface index number to the function "toggleAdmin" which is on my Nodes controller.  Then toggleAdmin would run the SNMP gem commands to check the current status of the specified interface, and set it to the opposite. After it finishes running, it would render 'show' again.

I have tried:

```
<% link_to "ToggleAdmin", :controller=>:nodes, :action=>:toggleAdmin %>
```

But I get:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"nodes", :action=>"toggleAdmin"}
```

What would I put in the routes file for this, and how can I tack on additional parameters from the view in order to have them passed in to the toggleAdmin function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In routes you can have this:

```
 get 'nodes/toggle_admin'
```

Then your `link_to` should work

```
<% link_to "ToggleAdmin", nodes_toggle_admin_path(:some_param => :value) %>
```

And yes, "toggleAdmin" does not conform to naming conventions. Should be "toggle_admin"

Comment: Do I need a "match" part in the routes entry, or just what you posted on its own line?

Comment: That line is kind of sugar for match.

Comment: `<% link_to "ToggleAdmin", :controller=>:nodes, :action=>:toggleAdmin, :node=>@theNode, :intIndex=>int[:intIndex], :intStatus=>int[:ifAdminStatus] %>`  Is my link, but when I click the link, I get a WEBrick RequestURITooLarge error.

Comment: Well, don't push the whole `@node` to the request, what good will it do? Push only its id.